# How does one stop the same name being written onto an external txt file in this program that tracks player scores?

Tags: python-3.x

Currently working on a simple project (I am very new to python) and am making a system where player names and scores are stored on a separate txt file, however, every time a player gets additional points it creates an entirely new entry instead of overwriting the first one. I am not sure how to do this and would appreciate some help!  Oh and please don't mind the terrible coding I am quite bad :D

```
def Game():
global randomartist
global randomsong
global randomsongfirst
global playername
global counter
global score
if counter > 1:
    sys.exit()
else:
    RandomSelect()
    print("Artist: ", randomartist)
    print("Song: ", randomsongfirst)
    print(randomsong)
    guess = input()
    if guess == randomsong:
        print("Correct! +5 points to ", playername)
        score = score + 5
        playername2 = (playername, str(score))
        namesscoresfile = open("namesscores.txt","a")
        namesscoresfile.write(str(playername2))
        namesscoresfile.write("\n")
        namesscoresfile.close()
        Game()
    elif guess != randomsong and counter == 0:
        print("Incorrect! ", playername," has one try left")
        counter = counter + 1
        Game()
    elif guess != randomsong and counter == 1:
        print("Game Over")
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are quite new to coding, I'll give some feedback about your program, so you can code better in the future :)

Firstly - the overall layout. I'd recommend renaming the function `Game()` to something like `turn()`, since it is really only a single turn. Also remove the recursive Game() calls from inside the function.

Try doing something like this inside your python file:

```py
def loadScore(name): #These are just placeholders to show where to put your functions
def writeScore(score, name): #They will cause an error; Make sure to put the actual functions here.
def turn(name):
def RandomSelect():

counter = 0
playername = "your name"
score = loadScore(playername) #I'll elaborate on this later

while counter < 2: #2 wrong answers tollerated
    correct = turn()
    if correct:
        score += 5
    else:
        counter += 1

writeScore(score, playername)
```

Now to fill out the function definitions:
`RandomSelect` should be left roughly the same, however instead of changing a global variable, return the values in a tuple. Here is an example RandomSelect function:

```py
def RandomSelect():
    n = random.randint(0, len(songs)) #Obviously songs is a list defined previously
    return arists[n], songs[n], songsfirst[n]
```

Now for your turn function:

```py
def turn():
    randomartist, randomsong, randomsongfirst = RandomSelect()
    print("Artist: ", randomartist)
    print("Song: ", randomsongfirst)
    print(randomsong)
    guess = input()
    if guess == randomsong:
        print("Correct! +5 points to ", playername)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Hopefully that all makes sense, because its about to get more complicated.
Now for your actual question:
There are many formats for storing data in a file, and many python libraries to help with them. An example is JSON. However, as practice we will not use any libraries.

Here is how I suggest we store the player scores in a file:

```
Bob 3
player1 4
randomname 1
```

etc.

The loadScore function:

```py
def loadScore(name):
    with open("namesscores.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines() #closing is automatic
    playerscores = {line.split(" ")[0]:line.split(" ")[1] for line in lines} # read up on list and dictionary comprehension for info on this syntax
    return int(playerscores[name]) # Remember to convert to a number.
```

The writeScore function:

```py
def writeScore(score, name): #This isn't a very good implementation but it will do.
    lines = []
    with open("namesscores.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.split(" ")[0] == name:
                lines.append(f"{name} {score}\n")
            else:
                lines.append(line)
    with open("namesscores.txt, "w") as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
```

Some important things:

- The functions `loadScore` and `writeScore` assume that the file exists, and that it already contains all usernames (even if their score is 0). If this is not the case there will be an error. This should be fixed; the best way is using try except blocks. Look them up.
- If you are using files, then you may as well put the song data in one as well.